# Getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am familiarizing myself with AngularJS and making calls to a Web API backend and I get the error of

> angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

I have a productListController

```
(function ()
{
"use strict";
angular.module("productManagement").controller("ProductListController", ["productResource", ProductListController]);
function ProductListController($scope, productResource) {

    productResource.query(function (data) {
        $scope.products = data
    });
}
})();
```

and I created a service called productResource

```
(function () {
"use strict";

angular.module("common.services").factory("productResource", ["$resource", "appSettings", productResource])

function productResource($resource, appSettings) {
    return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/products/:id").query();
}
}());
```

The appSettings is a constant that specifies a path.

Why is `query` undefined?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your controller is expecting the following dependencies to be injected:

```
$scope, productResource
```

and actually you are injecting only `"productResource"` instead of `"$scope", "productResource"`

Your controller should be initialised like this:

```
angular.module("productManagement").controller("ProductListController", ["$scope", "productResource", ProductListController]);

function ProductListController($scope, productResource) {
    // ...
}
```

The names of the dependencies passed in need to be in sync with the parameters in the controller function declaration - at the moment when you are injecting `"productResource"` it is going into the `$scope` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue a while ago and it took me hours to figure it out.

In certain cases you need to make sure that you inject `"productResource"` and `"$scope"` and follow a specific order. Let me demonstrate:

```
angular.module("productManagement").controller("ProductListController", ["$scope", "productResource", ProductListController]);  

    function ProductListController($scope, productResource) {
        // ...
    }
```

The above code will always work, but if you switch positions as seen below, in some cases (as I mentioned above), it won't work.

```
angular.module("productManagement").controller("ProductListController", ["productResource","$scope", ProductListController]);  

    function ProductListController($scope, productResource) {
        // ...
    }
```

I never had this issue of making sure dependencies are injected in the correct order until today. If after all this your code is still not working then the issue is probably elsewhere.
I hope this helps.